# Cocos2d-x won't build to windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

So with the newest release of cocos2d-x, I noticed the new project command generates a windows phone 8 folder to go along with the other auto generated projects.  However, upon opening the generated solution and trying to build I get this error:

> C:\Projects\MyGame\cocos2d\cocos\cocos2d.h(226): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'platform/winrt/CCGLViewImpl.h': No such
>   file or directory

The project builds for all the other platforms.  Is windows phone 8 officially supported yet?  Is there a quick work-around to get up and running?

(Also I have a windows phone developer account and can build other windows phone solutions, I am using visual studio pro 2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the latest version on github it now all works, so maybe it was still a work in progress.

(Note that it doesn't work in 3.2, the latest version posted on the website, but it does work in the latest github code as of now).